# How to disable Change Install Location button in packagemaker

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I need to disable/not show a Change Install Location button in installer. How do I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled relocation for both items I would need to install and leaved in the package configuration install on system volume. This removed the Change Install Location button in installer

Comment: I am having the same problem and I tried the steps you mentioned but the button is still there, even though there is only one HD present. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: somehow the relocate appears each time you change something in your archive. so be sure that it's not there each time BEFORE you build your installer